# Find out which scroll element has keyboard focus

Tags: javascript, html, css, overflow, keyboard-events

When having multiple elements with a scrollbar on one page (maybe by setting CSS `overflow-scroll`) the arrow keys on the keyboard do always only scroll one area (which is a good thing). It seems that always the last element with scrollbars I clicked on with the mouse recognizes the key events and scroll ([example on Codepen](https://codepen.io/medihack/pen/PeOGWY)).

Is there a way to find out which element (a `div` element in the above example) has keyboard "focus" (quotes as it doesn't seem to get a focus pseudoclass, see example above)?

Comment: [`document.activeElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/activeElement)

Comment: nope, it reports `body` even if one can scroll a little `div` on the page, see the updated example: https://codepen.io/medihack/pen/PeOGWY

Comment: Was easier than I thought. Hope my answer helps. @Kushtrim posted the same before me realizing now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add `tabindex` to your *outer* or scroll elements and then use `document.activeElement`

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  let a = document.activeElement;
  console.log(a);
})
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.outer-left {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.inner-left {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
}

.outer-right {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.inner-right {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="outer-left" tabindex="1">
    <div class="inner-left">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="outer-right" tabindex="2">
    <div class="inner-right">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add `tabindex="0"` to the div.

https://codepen.io/gezzasa/pen/QrOdqX